# How to add author images to blog articles on a Voog site?

Tags: html, voog

I have a blog on my Voog website (http://voog.com). It’s currently in construction but we’re adding some content before launching it, and I need to add images to the authors. Until now, I’ve been the only one posting the articles and I managed to hardcode my image next to my name and timestamp:

`<img class="author-image" src="{{ images_path }}/my-profile-image.jpg">`

But now we have multiple people posting the articles and I need a better solution. Can I build this solution on elements? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround can be like this:
title - author's name
image - author's image
email - author's e-mail

For example:
`<img src="/photos/{{ article.author.firstname }}.jpg">`

or a more advanced example:
`<img src="/photos/{{ article.author.firstname }}{{ article.author.lastname }}.jpg">`

All you need to do is update the first and last name on the editor's profile (https://youtu.be/-RXnoyrsXU0), upload the image to your files menu with the correct name and the system will recognize it.

If this is not the exact solution you're looking for, then yes, it's possible to create an element-based system but this requires site-specific examples and needs to be built on multiple pages. Do get in contact with [Voog](http://www.voog.com/support/contact) for this solution!